# Allow SSO using Office265 in Cognito for any Office365 account

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate Office365 as an Identity Provider for Cognito.

Following instructions from AWS (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-amazon-cognito-for-federated-authentication-using-azure-ad/) and a few other sources all have the same instructions.

Those instructions work, but they only allow users that are already in my Azure AD to use SSO. I need this to work just like social accounts (Google, Facebook).

Any advice on how to modify the above-linked instructions to work with any valid Office365 credentials, even if the account is not in my Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

try adding app registration instead of enterprise app

[image]

Comment: This approach doesn't accept the cognito format for Application ID URI, which is of format urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-2_XXXXXXXX.  Can you provide with a link or documentation somewhere that states this is the proper process? Because it doesn't seem like it for me.